# При выводе на печать таблицы нет рамки

Tags: jquery, css3, html5

Вывожу на печать динамически сформированную таблицу, но по-чему то нет стилей, а именно отрисовки рамок, выводится просто текст в колонках. Да и ещё, вывожу только таблицу из всего контента.

```js
$('#account_calcButton5').on('click', function() {
  let divToPrint = $("#account_calcLayoutGrid3").html();
  newWin = window.open();
  newWin.document.write(divToPrint);
  newWin.print();
  newWin.close();
});
```

```css
.table-bordered {
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table-bordered th {
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
}

.table-bordered td,
.table-bordered th {
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="account_calcLayoutGrid3" style="display: inline-block;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1">
      <table class="shopping_list table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-sm table-responsive-xl text-center">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">№</th>
            <th scope="col">Материал</th>
            <th scope="col">Фото</th>
            <th scope="col">Раскрой по:</th>
            <th scope="col">Система</th>
            <th scope="col">Штапик</th>
            <th scope="col">Управление</th>
            <th scope="col">Ширина,см</th>
            <th scope="col">Высота,см</th>
            <th scope="col">Кол-во,шт</th>
            <th scope="col">Цена,руб</th>
            <th scope="col">Удалить</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="jqcart-tr" data-id="0">
            <td class="align-middle">1</td>
            <td class="align-middle"> 9700</td>
            <td><img src="imagesbd/gor_images/gor_001.png" style="width:80px;"></td>
            <td class="align-middle"></td>
            <td class="align-middle">Горизонтальные-Стандарт</td>
            <td class="align-middle"></td>
            <td class="align-middle">Слева</td>
            <td class="align-middle">50</td>
            <td class="align-middle">130</td>
            <td class="align-middle">1</td>
            <td class="align-middle itogSum">940.00 руб.</td>
            <td class="align-middle"><img class="deleteBusOut"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="text-right" colspan="11">Итого за изделия:</td>
            <td class="subItog"><strong>940.00 руб.</strong></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="wb_account_calcLayoutGrid6">
  <div id="account_calcLayoutGrid6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1">
        <input type="submit" id="account_calcButton5" name="" value="Оформить заказ" style="display: inline-block;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Пробовал использовать @media print но результат нулевой, сделал так

```js
$('table, th, td').css({'border':'1px solid black','border-collapse':'collapse'}); 
   let divToPrint = $("#account_calcLayoutGrid3").html();
   newWin = window.open();
   newWin.document.write(divToPrint);
   newWin.print();
   newWin.close();
   $('table, th, td').css({'border':'','border-collapse':''});
```

т.е. добавил стили в див вывел на печать и удалил стили.